# chart.js working fine on my localhost but it is not working online

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js

chart.js working fine on my localhost without any problems but when i publish it online it doesn't work... i receive pie chart data from another page using .load

below my HTML code:

```
<div id="canvas-holder">
<div  id="arafa" hidden></div>
<canvas id="chart-area"></canvas>   
</div>
```

and the below is my Jquery code

```
window.onload = function () {
                $("#arafa").load("home_reports/profit_and_loses.php", {}, function () {
                    var income = $.trim($('#arafa').html());
                    var code = income.split("|");
                    var first_code =  code[0];
                    var second_code =  code[1];
                        var pieData = [
                        {

                            value: first_code,
                            color:"#F7464A",
                            highlight: "#FF5A5E",
                            label: "income"
                        },
                        {
                            value: second_code,
                            color: "#46BFBD",
                            highlight: "#5AD3D1",
                            label: "expenses"
                        },

                    ];
                        var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area").getContext("2d");
                        window.myPie = new Chart(ctx).Pie(pieData);

                });
```

}

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any error with your ajax call on home_reports/profit_and_loses.php ? What is your console saying ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, chart function is being called before it get the data.

```
window.onload = function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var ctx = document.getElementById("valueChart").getContext("2d");
        window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
            responsive: true
        });
    }, 1000);

}
```

Suppose it is just an example of your solution to understand. Here **lineChartData** is the data object to show in the chart. And to handle this data within the chart I have used a **settimeout** function with 1 second delay. You can check with this code if your problem is late loading or not, if yes then you can create any other event handler to load your objects and functions serially.